# Symfony 4.1 and Doctrine asossiation Problems

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I read a lot Postings on Stackoverflow and the doctrine Documentation but i cannot find the error in this code. Maybe someone can lead me to the right direction as i'm sure i don't get the point on this concept. This is my first Project with doctrine.

I have three entities and the Database is generated correct but i always get these Errors when doing

php ./bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

the entities are as follows (shortened):

> [FAIL] The entity-class App\Entity\DeployedTrap mapping is invalid:  *
>   The association App\Entity\DeployedTrap#trapId refers to the inverse
>   side field App\Entity\TrapDefinition#id which is not defined as
>   association.  * The association App\Entity\DeployedTrap#trapId refers
>   to the inverse side field App\Entity\TrapDefinition#id which does not
>   exist.  * The association App\Entity\DeployedTrap#customer refers to
>   the inverse side field App\Entity\Customer#customerId which is not
>   defined as association.  * The association
>   App\Entity\DeployedTrap#customer refers to the inverse side field
>   App\Entity\Customer#customerId which does not exist.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="traps_deployed")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DeployedTrapRepository")
 */
class DeployedTrap
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * Owning side
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="trap_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TrapDefinition", inversedBy="id")
     */
    public $trapId;

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer", referencedColumnName="customerId")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer", inversedBy="customerId")
     */
    private $customer;




}
```

Class TrapDefinition:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="traps_definition")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TrapDefinitionRepository")
 */
class TrapDefinition
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DeployedTrap", mappedBy="trapId")
     */
    public $id;





    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = new ArrayCollection();
    }


}
```

class Customer:

```
    namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="customerId",length=11, nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DeployedTrap", mappedBy="customer")
     */
    public $customerId;




    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->customerId = new ArrayCollection();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Forget the native database approach for linking Models via Id's (see `$trapId` in your `DeployerTrap`) in Doctrine. You will always link objects/collections to each other so `$trapId` should be `$trapDefinition`.

And that is your main problem here

Just add a field `$deployerTraps` to your `TrapDefinition` class

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DeployedTrap", mappedBy="trapDefinition")
*/
public $deployerTraps;
```

And rename the `$trapId` to `$trapDefinition` in your `DeployedTrap` class

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="TrapDefinition", inversedBy="deployerTraps")
 */
public $trapDefinition;
```

Comment: Side note: avoid bidirectional relationships whenever you can.

Comment: What is the reason for that? The use case for don't adding a bidirectional relationship is really rare to me ... whenever i need a relation to another model not very much later i need the connection vice versa

Comment: Long story short: performance. You don't always need both sides. But that depends on your domain requirements.